# Where is "status" located in the database from Magento 2 order grid

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, sales-order, order-status

I want to change all the orders that are in the status of "Processing" to "Complete" state.

I managed to find this in the `sales_order` table and set the state and status to complete. This worked fine and when I access the order, the state and status are now "Complete":

[image]

However, in the admin grid, it is still showing "Processing". How can I change this directly in the database?:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rakesh Donga pointed out the two Queries but more specific queries based on your situation

```
UPDATE sales_order SET state='complete', status='complete' WHERE status = 'processing'
UPDATE sales_order_grid SET status='complete' WHERE status = 'processing'
```

After you update the sales_order and sales_order_grid table, you also have to add record in sales_order_status_history table as well by inserting the row against each order. Example row insert query

```
INSERT INTO `sales_order_status_history` (`parent_id`, `is_customer_notified`, `is_visible_on_front`, `comment`, `status`, `created_at`, `entity_name`) VALUES (1, 0, 0, NULL, 'complete', NOW(), 'order');
```

In this query parent_id is order entity_id.

I hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

The first query will update the state and status on the table sales_order.

```
mysql> UPDATE sales_order SET state='complete', status='complete' WHERE increment_id IN (000043719,000044003,000044117,...);
Query OK, 15 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Rows matched: 16  Changed: 15  Warnings: 0
```

The second one will update the status in the grid view in Sales > Orders.

```
mysql> UPDATE sales_order_grid SET status='complete' WHERE increment_id IN (000043719,000044003,000044117,...);
Query OK, 15 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 16  Changed: 15  Warnings: 0
```